# How to prevent mildew in the shower?

Tags: cleaning, bathroom

Mildew builds up between the wall tiles of my shower. Mildew removal spray works, but smells awful. Is there a way to prevent mildew buildup in this situation without using foul smelling chemicals?

Answer (score 5):

***What you can use:***

- [Bleach or Vinegar](http://www.wikihow.com/Prevent-Mildew-on-Shower-Curtain). Making a bleach or vinegar solution that should be sprayed across the walls and curtains.

> To make a natural cleaning solution, mix together 1 part warm water
>   and 1 part distilled white vinegar and pour the mixture into a spray
>   bottle.
>
> You can substitute bleach for vinegar; however, you will be required
>   to properly ventilate your bathroom after using the bleach mixture to
>   prevent adverse health effects from the toxic fumes.

Never mix Bleach with other cleaning products unless you know what your doing, this can result in maiming or death. Bleach can be strong, vinegar works fine. White vinegar is best and other vinegars can be to sugary and cause other problems. Alos, white vinegar is stronger.

- Spraying mixtures of peperminty or tea tree oil essential oils work for me and leave a fabulous smell.

Here is a recipe that uses vinegar. [Here:](http://www.care2.com/greenliving/vinegar-with-essential-oils-for-mold-and-mildew.html)

> The problem is that many people write to me saying that they hate the
>   smell of vinegar. What to do? I’ve been experimenting with adding a
>   few drops of essential oil to straight white distilled vinegar and the
>   results for smell are remarkable and unexpected. The essential oils
>   seem to mellow out the bite of the smell of vinegar, leaving a vibrant
>   essence that is mostly the smell of the essential oil with a bit of a
>   sharp almost resinous touch, which would be the transformed vinegar.

- Hydrogen Peroxide also works but may have to be applied more often. This product is known to rid mould, as well.

---

***Other things that work:***

- Cleaning the fans in the bathroom.
- Drying the bathroom, curtains and other wet objects after leaving the bathroom. Good ventilation is key.

[Things to do to prevent Mildew.](http://www.care2.com/greenliving/how-to-prevent-mold-and-mildew-in-your-shower.html)

Comment: Extra point for drying it. Keep a squeegee or wiper handy and wipe it down after every shower. Also if you have a curtain hang it straight to let it dry too.

Comment: If you use strong vinegar often it will attack the grout between the tiles. Bear this in mind.

Answer (score 2):

*Generously* spray white vinegar on the walls at night and rinse it down the next morning.

Reference: http://www.ehow.com/how_5948342_eliminate-mildew-vinegar.html

Answer (score 1):

You can make a solution of bleach and water:

> - 3 parts bleach
> - 2 parts warm water

Mix this inside of a spray bottle, and spray the solution on the already existing mildew. You can then just wipe it off, and this solution will prevent future mildew.

Answer (score 0):

Vinegar is a proven anti-bacterial agent.  Keep a spray bottle filled with white vinegar in the shower and spray areas prone to mildew every few days.  Do this after a thorough cleaning.

Comment: Except mildew is fungus, not bacteria.